# How can I change the color/put things behind my ViewControlller's view (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

First, an image:[image: here]

I made it so you can drag the view controller view with your finger (which I have already done), but I want to know:

1. How to change the black color to another color
2. How I can put an image behind the view (I want to make it so if you drag the view you'll see a picture).

How do I do this? I figure I'll need to place another view directly behind this one maybe and then make make current view controlller a sub view?

Comment: You could set your background picture into the view controller's `view` and then make the one you want to move a subview of that.

Comment: you can do it through added imageview at backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an image as the background of your `ViewController` by either changing the class of your `ViewController`'s main view from `UIView` to `UIImageView` in `Storyboard` and setting the image to that `ImageView`'s `image` property or by adding a `UIImageView` to the `ViewController` that has the same size as `view`.

Answer (score 0):

By "background color", I think you mean the black color that shows when you drag the VC away, right?

That is the color of the `UIWindow` that you VC is running in. It's kind of the superview of every view.

To change the windows color, simply go to your `AppDelegate.swift` and change change it:

```
window?.backgroundColor = .red
```

To add a background image, you just need to add a `UIImageView` as a subview of `window`.

```
if let window = self.window
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: window.frame)
    imageView.image = ...
    window.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with subviews and only use viewcontrollers, you can try to present a draggable viewcontroller over a normal (fixed position) viewcontroller. You can do it like this (call this code from the normal view controller to present the draggable view controller over itself):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

// Set the draggable controller's identifier in Main.storyboard
let dragController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DragController")

// Present the draggable view controller over the current one
dragController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
dragController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
self.present(dragController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Use this code, and then set the background image of the normal view controller. Hope this helps :)